# XPath Expression referencing a node

Tags: xpath

I am trying to reference a node in an expression. Take this simple example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<homelist>
     <homes>
        <home>
             <hname>house</hname>
             <location>hell</location>
             <url>wee</url>
             <cID>1234</cID>
        </home>
     </homes>
     <contacts>
           <contactdetails cID="1234">
               <cname>John Smith</cname>
               <phone>0123234</phone>
               <email>test@gmail.com</email>
           </contactdetails>
     </contacts>
  </homelist>
```

I basically want to select nodes if it's value is somewhere else in the tree.

For example, I want to display the url of homes that have cID of John Smith. I tried this but it doesn't work, what is wrong with it:

```
 homelist/homes/home[ancestor::homelist/contacts/contactdetails[cname="John Smith"]/url
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
"/homelist/homes/home[cID = /homelist/contacts/contactdetails[cname='John Smith']/@cID]/url"
```

You want to find the `<home>` whose `<cID>` child's text content equals that of the `cID=` attribute of the `<contactdetails>` whose `<cname>` contains `'John Smith'`, then return its `<url>` child.

Note that I've written this as an absolute path, from the root, since you didn't tell us what the context node was going to be for this XPath.

There are certainly other ways of writing the same concept; this is just the first one that occurred to me offhand.

If you preferred to use `ancestor` or `parent`, you could say

```
"/homelist/homes/home[cID = ancestor::homelist/contacts/contactdetails[cname='John Smith']/@cID]/url"
```

Comment: Hi I am trying out the top one. The context node it homelist. I don't seem to get any results, why?

Comment: I admit that this is untested code, but if the input is really what you showed us it _should_ work. (Are you running it on a different input that might have, eg, namespace declarations?) Simplest way to debug this sort of thing is to try breaking it down into simpler XPaths and see if they produce the results you expect.

Comment: Yes the xml is the same. I am breaking down the expression into two parts and I do get results, but the whole thing does not.

Comment: Capitalization. Sorry; should have proofread that (and you should have too)... `contactdetails`, not `contactDetails`. XML is case-sensitive, after all. I'll fix the answer.

Comment: OK, I can try to find time to test it properly. Other than that, trying subexpressions should enable you to debug it about as easily as I can, right?

Comment: Actually your expression does work. But strangely I get no results in http://www.bit-101.com/xpath/ (which I was using before). I looked at other examples and they use the structure that you wrote, why I had no results confused me. I tried another tool http://www.xmlme.com/XpathTool.aspx and it gave me the expected results.

Comment: I can't be responsible for broken implementations... other than IBM's and Apache's, which I had a hand in. (Can't be reponsible for Sun's either, since last I checked it was an outdated version of Apache's with known bugs.)